# Opening a PDF in a new page

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have created a PDF and I am trying to open it in a new window (or new tab, but I have the new window working right now)

Here is my aspx code. The link button is in a GridView which is in a Panel, which is in an Update Panel (Yeah, I've seen people having problems with Update panels and this, but I have to do it this way).

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="ReportLink" runat="server" CommandName="GenReport" 
          CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' 
          OnClientClick="LoadPDF()" PostBackUrl="~/Indices/myPDF.aspx"
          Text="View Report" ToolTip="Genereate a PDF of the Report"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Here is my javascript that opens the new window

```
function LoadPDF() {
    window.open('myPDF.aspx', '',
    'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no');
}
```

and here is the C#. The first snippet is what gets called when the linkbutton is clicked (after the javascript). The second is the method that actually creates the PDF and attempts to send it to the new window.

```
{
     DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["IndexTable"]; //copy of the GirdView
     int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
     DataRow row = dt.Rows[rowIndex];
     GenerateReport(row["ITEM_ID"].ToString());
}

private void GenerateReport(string itemID)
{
    OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connstr);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        //code here omitted, all sql and setting up info for the doc
        // giving TurnOverData a dataset

        ReportDocument doc = new ReportDocument();
        doc.FileName = Server.MapPath("myRpt.rpt");
        doc.SetDataSource(TurnoverData);


        //here adding parameters to doc

        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = (System.IO.MemoryStream)doc.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);//leftover code from previous functionality (i dont think it is doing anything)

       BinaryReader Bin = new BinaryReader(doc.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat));
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ContentType="application/pdf";
        Response.BinaryWrite(Bin.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(Bin.BaseStream.Length)));
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.logError("GenerateReport()  " + ex.Message);
        Utilities.SendAnAlert(this, "An error occurred while generating PDF file and the file could not be displayed.");
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

After much digging through our old code I found a work around. Nearly all of the code you guys suggested to me was already in our code, I just needed to figure out how to use what we had. I ended up using my LoadPDF function but had to pass it a string argument because the url used"?= " that I had to fill in. I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Why does this need to be done via javascript?

Would a

```
<a href="myPDF.aspx" target="_blank">blah</a>
```

do the trick?

**EDIT**

I did some research, and you are using `Request.Close()` incorrectly.  According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.close.aspx), that method is "not intended for normal HTTP request processing".

Perhaps you should use `Request.End()` instead.

Changing that line should fix it, but I would also consider changing

```
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = (System.IO.MemoryStream)doc.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);//leftover code from previous functionality (i dont think it is doing anything)

        BinaryReader Bin = new BinaryReader(doc.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat));
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ContentType="application/pdf";
        Response.BinaryWrite(Bin.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(Bin.BaseStream.Length)));
        Response.Flush();
```

to something more like

```
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = (System.IO.MemoryStream)doc.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);

        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ContentType="application/pdf";
        stream.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.Flush();
```

But if it works, it works.

Comment: It seems that the issue is in generating actual PDF file, not opening up the browser window (and there is no ajax mentioned in the post btw).

Comment: I tried this one as well, and it opens the new tab ajust fine, but my pdf is still not being displayed. I think my main issue is just getting my pdf to show.

Comment: I didn't realize the problem was in the rendering of the PDF.  I thought you just needed to open it in a new tab.  I have updated my answer.  Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding Content-Disposition/Content-Length headers to your response:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"report.pdf\"");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", Bin.BaseStream.Length);
```

Comment: This will cause the pdf to be downloaded, not opened in a new tab.  Also you have typos in your code (I don't have the rep to edit it).

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it doesn't seem to help, as in it is still doing the same thing.

Comment: It looks like the issue could be in your report generating code. I'd suggest trying to save the Bin object to disk and see if you can open resulting pdf file locally.

Comment: I know that the pdf is being generated properly, we were previously saving the file to a server, but they dont want that anymore. They want the pdf to be generated and displayed on the spot.

Comment: So you verified that it is, indeed, working with your current code (i.e. PDF is being generated)? The response code (with Content-Disposition/Content-Length headers added) look good otherwise, so issue must be something else.

Comment: Yes, the PDF is definitely being generated. I have gone through some other options and it pretty much comes up with an error every time I try to do any kind of 'Response.Write'. It gives me the 'PageRequestManagerParserErrorException' error and where it is parsing incorrectly. Thanks for all the help so far!